# Convert PHP MySQL to PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to convert this PHP MySQL code from:

```
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
if(!empty($_POST["primary_cat"])) {
    $query ="SELECT DISTINCT `secondary_cat` FROM student5 WHERE primary_cat = '" . $_POST["primary_cat"] . "'";
    $results = $db_handle->runQuery($query);
    ?>
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <?php
    foreach($results as $state) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $state["secondary_cat"]; ?>"><?php echo $state["secondary_cat"]; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
```

to PHP PDO as follows. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. This is my code below.

```
$table = 'student5';
include('config.php');

if(!empty($_POST['primary_cat'])) {
$sqlQuerySecondaryCat = $dbh->query("SELECT DISTINCT secondary_cat FROM $table WHERE primary_cat = :primary_cat");
$sqlQuerySecondaryCat->execute(array(':primary_cat' => $_POST['primary_cat']));

    ?>
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <?php
    foreach($sqlQuerySecondaryCat as $secondaryCatRow) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $secondaryCatRow["secondary_cat"]; ?>"><?php echo $secondaryCatRow["secondary_cat"]; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error in my error_log `PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: Where do you instance your $dbh? in config.php ?

Comment: its in another exernal file called config.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to use `prepare`, not `query`.

```
$sqlQuerySecondaryCat->prepare("SELECT .......
```

Secondly, you haven't done anything with the data stored in the object `$sqlQuerySecondaryCat` - you need to use `fetch` or `fetchAll` for the data.

```
$data = $sqlQuerySecondaryCat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($data as $secondaryCatRow){
    .... do something
```

**Full code:**

```
$table = 'student5';
include('config.php');

if(!empty($_POST['primary_cat'])) {
    $sqlQuerySecondaryCat = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT secondary_cat FROM $table WHERE primary_cat = :primary_cat");
    $sqlQuerySecondaryCat->execute(array(':primary_cat' => $_POST['primary_cat']));
    $rows = $sqlQuerySecondaryCat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); ?>
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    <?php foreach($rows as $secondaryCatRow) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $secondaryCatRow["secondary_cat"]; ?>"><?php echo $secondaryCatRow["secondary_cat"]; ?></option>
    <?php }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it work. Kindly why did you use 'fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)'

Comment: `fetch()` gets the data for the next row as an array. `fetchAll()` gets the data for ALL received rows as an array. `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` gets the data as an array with column names for keys. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php. I'm glad I could help - if it worked don't forget to accept as an answer!